# また上手くなってく 理由の Why is there a く after なって?

Tags: grammar, contractions

言い訳が また上手くなって**く** 理由の

Is **く** there to connect the sentence?
I'm probably overthinking this but it bugs me not understanding the purpose of this **く**.

By the way, this is a lyric from this song; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EejcsaMDduQ

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Without listening to the song, this is simply changing うまい (上手い) into "adverbial" use to connect with なる (as all イ-"adjectives" do).</strike>

> うまい　→　うま**く**なる

Oops, wrong く.  This is just the contracted form of なって**いく**, which is modifying 理由.

Comment: I had a feeling it could be なっていく but wasn't sure. I really appreciate you explaining this to me. Thank you!